# Firebase Performance Plugin won't build on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-performance

I managed to add the Firebase Perfomance Module to iOS and to Web App but for some reason I can't add it to Android, it fails to build and shows a lot of errors!

I've attached the build logs with different options (--info, --stack-trace, --scan)

Can anyone help me please?

Normal Build Log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xSJUyyndSW6psUHIMHw5VptTWc4quLfI/view?usp=sharing

Build with --info: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M_iN0iSkBlFnRt0PW7itTEdxAS-F6r1X/view?usp=sharing

Build with --stack-trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IUNQvADORvYbEPUtYHhLQcObWJfcWGnY/view?usp=sharing

Build with --scan: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19kH1bRVFKPih_NP9V86aDuO1EDhydjaE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly for help troubleshooting Firebase products.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I wish I could, I tried contacting them through that form but the form gives me an error "Error submitting request. Please try again later.", I am trying for 3 days...

Comment: Actually, there is a problem with the upload field, I managed to contact them now but without uploading the files, I sent the build logs links, thanks for helping.

Comment: Sorry you had problems with that.  Firebase support is aware of occasional problems with file attachments.  It would actually be very helpful, if you have time, to file another bug report showing the web console log with the detailed error message that happens on submit, as the issue is difficult to reproduce.